# Pause script until simultaneous commands end

Tags: powershell

I have two jobs that I created in a powershell script:

```
$job1= Start-Job {
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("service", $var1 $var2 $var3)
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("service", $var1 $var2 $var3)
}

$job2= Start-Job {
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("service", $var1 $var2 $var3)
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("service", $var1 $var2 $var3)
}
```

I want the process in job1 to finish before starting job2. I have tried    Wait Job, Get Job | Wait Job, but when I run Receive Job it shows the job has completed. I am assuming it considers it complete after the job has technically ran even though 2 new cmd windows open and the job is still running.

How do I get powershell to recognize these windows are still open/running so they do not continue until completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your calls to

```
$p1 = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("service", $var1 $var2 $var3)
$p2 = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("service", $var1 $var2 $var3)
$p1.WaitForExit()
$p2.WaitForExit()
```

which will ensure that your job is not considered complete before the processes it started complete.
With that in place you can then use `Wait-Job` on `$job1` to wait until the processes in there finish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply DAX. This partially does what I need it to do. Yes, it keeps the cmd window from closing and waits to exit, but now it doesn't allow each [Diagnostics.Process] in the jobs to run in parallel. It would be nice to apply the .WaitforExit() to the whole job, or all processes somehow, and not the processes individually.

Comment: I made a quick edit so the processes will run in parallel

Comment: And that quick edit did the trick. Appreciate the quick response on this!